# ElasticSearch EJS query to fetch missing field

Tags: javascript, database, elasticsearch

I have an existing ejs query as below:

```
let queryBody = ejs.Request()
      .size(0)
      .query(
        ejs.BoolQuery()
          .must(
            ejs.RangeQuery('hour_time_stamp').gte(this.lastDeviceDate).lte(this.lastDeviceDate)
          )
      )
      .agg(ejs.TermsAggregation('market_agg').field('market').order('sum', 'asc').size(50000)
        .agg(ejs.SumAggregation('sum').field('num_devices'))
      )
```

currently the field('market') returns the values where data for market is present. There is data in the database for missing values for market as well, which I need to access. How do I do that?

---

EDIT:
Values for market in ES is either null or field is missing. I wrote ES query to get all those fields but I am not able to incorporate an ejs query for the same. Any idea how this can be done?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "market"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "market"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem you need a way to group the empty market fields too.
So for that you can use the "missing" value parameter. It defines how the values which are missing(as in your case) are grouped. So you query in json form will be modified like below :-

```
{
"query":
    {
        "must": [
            "range": {
                "hour_time_stamp": {
                    "gte": lastDeviceDate,
                    "lte": lastDeviceDate
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "aggs": {
        "market_agg" : {
            "market": {
                "missing": "empty_markets",
                "order": { "sum": "asc" }
            }
        },
        "sum_agg": {
            "sum" : { "field" : "num_devices" }
        }
    }
}
```

Or in your code it could be done by adding missing parameter like this.

```
let queryBody = ejs.Request()
      .size(0)
      .query(
        ejs.BoolQuery()
          .must(
            ejs.RangeQuery('hour_time_stamp').gte(this.lastDeviceDate).lte(this.lastDeviceDate)
          )
      )
      .agg(ejs.TermsAggregation('market_agg').field('market').missing('empty_markets').order('sum', 'asc').size(50000)
        .agg(ejs.SumAggregation('sum').field('num_devices'))
      )
```

Comment: I have edited the question with my progress. Can you have a look @ashutosh ?